# Setting Connection attributes for DataDefModel.PropertyBag in Crystal Reports to connect to SQL Express 2005/2008

Tags: c#, .net, sql, crystal-reports, sql-server-express

How should I modify the below code so that I can use these connection attributes to connect to a Microsoft sql express 2005 or 2008 database

```
 CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.DataDefModel.PropertyBag connectionAttributes = new CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.DataDefModel.PropertyBag();
        connectionAttributes.EnsureCapacity(11);
        connectionAttributes.Add("Connect Timeout", "15");
        connectionAttributes.Add("Data Source", serverName);
        connectionAttributes.Add("General Timeout", "0");
        connectionAttributes.Add("Initial Catalog", databaseName);
        connectionAttributes.Add("Integrated Security", false);
        connectionAttributes.Add("Locale Identifier", "1033");
        connectionAttributes.Add("OLE DB Services", "-5");
        connectionAttributes.Add("Provider", "SQLOLEDB");
        connectionAttributes.Add("Tag with column collation when possible", "0");
        connectionAttributes.Add("Use DSN Default Properties", false);
        connectionAttributes.Add("Use Encryption for Data", "0");

        DbConnectionAttributes attributes = new DbConnectionAttributes();
        attributes.Collection.Add(new NameValuePair2("Database DLL", "crdb_ado.dll"));
        attributes.Collection.Add(new NameValuePair2("QE_DatabaseName", databaseName));
        attributes.Collection.Add(new NameValuePair2("QE_DatabaseType", "OLE DB (ADO)"));
        attributes.Collection.Add(new NameValuePair2("QE_LogonProperties", connectionAttributes));
        attributes.Collection.Add(new NameValuePair2("QE_ServerDescription", serverName));
        attributes.Collection.Add(new NameValuePair2("SSO Enabled", false));

        ConnectionInfo connectionInfo =GetConnectionInfo(serverName, databaseName, userID, password);
        connectionInfo.Attributes = attributes;
        connectionInfo.Type = ConnectionInfoType.SQL;
```